# Fitting a curve over bar chart. [Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I have a bar chart and I need to characterize the distribution of the data. Now, I'm positive that my data follow the geometric distribution but I can't fit a curve on the data neither can I plot the probability mass function.

```
plt.bar(range(len(freq)), [val[1] for val in freq], log=True, alpha=0.75)
plt.xticks(range(len(freq)), [val[0] for val in freq])
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.xlabel('Times a word appears in the collection',labelpad=1)
plt.ylabel('Number of words appearing x times')
```

[image]

How can I fit a curve on this data to prove my data follow the geometric distribution?

I should note also, that my data is a list of tuples.

Comment: If you cannot fit a curve, you cannot plot that curve. Why would you ask about plotting if the problem is much earlier? Now it does not look like you have attempted anything in terms of fitting. In how far do other questions not help here? In the unusual case they wouldn't, it may make sense to ask a question. But you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. the piece of code you have attempted and that fails. Make sure to tag the question with the tool you are using for fitting, e.g. scipy, statsmodels, sklearn or whatever it may be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit a curve to a histogram in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544233/fit-a-curve-to-a-histogram-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the data and function in this example, I think it is close to what you are asking about.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


# "x" is data, a,b,c are parameters
def func(x, a, b, c):
   return a + b*x + c*x*x # example function


xData = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
yData = np.array([1,3,5,6,2,1])

# curve fit the data using curve_fit's default inital parameter estimates
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData)

y_fit = func(xData, *fittedParameters)

plt.bar(xData, yData) # plot the raw data as bar chart
plt.plot(xData, y_fit) # plot the equation using the fitted parameters
plt.show()

print(fittedParameters)
```